# ASP.NET Core - How to update existing record and insert a new one at the same time using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Entity Framework, I want the application to perform update and insert on the same model in the database at the same time.

I have this code:

```
public async Task<Response<string>> CreateIdentiticationAsync(CreateIdentiticationDto model)
{
    var response = new Response<string>();
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
            try
            {
                var identification = _mapper.Map<Identification>(model);
                var existingIdentifications = await _dbContext.Identifications.Where(e => e.IsModified == false).ToListAsync();
                foreach (var existingIdentification in existingIdentifications)
                {
                    if (existingIdentification != null)
                    {
                        existingIdentification.IsModified = true;
                        _unitOfWork.UserIdentifications.Update(identification);
                        await _unitOfWork.Save();
                    }
                }
                Identification.IsModified = false;
                Identification.Type = model.Type;
                Identification.Name = model.Name;

                await _unitOfWork.UserIdentifications.InsertAsync(identification);
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                response.Successful = true;
                response.Message = "Created Successfully!";
                transaction.Complete();
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Dispose();
                response.Message = "An error occured";
                response.Successful = false;
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return response;
            }
    }
}
```

When user wants to insert a new record, I want the application to first check the model, if no record exists it should just insert the new record.

But if it exists, it should update all the IsModified to true, and then go ahead and also insert a new record.

However, when no record exists, I was able to insert new record.
But where I have issue is that when it wants to update and insert new record, I got this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_identifications'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.identifications'. The duplicate key value is (81fe9b8d-2d9c-4d49-8f92-22afe043e327).

**Note: Id is Guid and autogenerated**

How do I resolve this?

Comment: DbContext doesn't need a TransactionScope or "UnitOfWork"- it already *is* a Unit of Work. It tracks all changes and persists *all* of them in a database transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. Calling `Save()` in a loop either does nothing or breaks the Unit-of-Work functionality. I suspect that's why you added a `TransactionScope` on top. That only covers up the problem though

Comment: What is `_unitOfWork` and what does its `Save` method do? Unless it's a no-op, it can only cause problems. How is `Identifications` defined? What is the primary key and how is it set? If it was database generated there would be no duplicates. If EF Core was used as intended, there would be no duplicates either, even if you tried to attach the same detached object twice. You'd get that error only if two different objects had an identical PK value

Comment: What does this code do? It seems like one part updating the `identification` object N times, one for every stored unmodified object. Another is *inserting* the same `identification` that was already updated N times. And yet another is modifying the unrelated `Identification` object but never storing it. If you wanted to store the `identification` object you'd need just two lines, `_context. Update(identification); _context.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things to consider here, in modern EF, I would not use a unitOfWork also a transaction is not needed unless very specific cases, you should also validate the ID from your incoming model value is null since ID is supposed to be autogenerated (most likely this is the source of your error). Since I don't know the name of your PK field, I will not introduce such validation in my proposed code.

One last recommendation, avoid this code on your controller, it breaks Single Responsibility Principle. Create a layer where you perform your business tasks and call this layer from your controller.

Here is a simplified proposed code which should work, don't forget to ensure the value in the model ID is coming as null.

```
public async Task<Response<string>> CreateIdentiticationAsync(CreateIdentiticationDto model)
{
    var response = new Response<string>();
    try
    {
        var identification = _mapper.Map<Identification>(model);
        var existingIdentifications = await _dbContext.Identifications.Where(e => e.IsModified == false).ToListAsync();
        foreach (var existingIdentification in existingIdentifications)
        {
            existingIdentification.IsModified = true;
        }

        Identification.IsModified = false;

        // If you already mapped this in line 6 why map those two fields again manually?
        // Identification.Type = model.Type;
        // Identification.Name = model.Name;

        _dbContext.UpdateRange(existingIdentifications);
        _dbContext.Add(identification);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
        response.Successful = true;
        response.Message = "Created Successfully!";

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Dispose();
        response.Message = "An error occured";
        response.Successful = false;
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public IActionResult Update(int? id,UpdateEmployeeVM employeeVM)
    {
        ViewBag.Positions = new SelectList(_context.Positions, nameof(Position.Id), nameof(Position.Name));
        Employee existed=_context.Employees.Find(id);
        if(existed==null) { NotFound();}
        if (!_context.Positions.Any(p => p.Id == employeeVM.PositionId)) ModelState.AddModelError("PoitionId", "Choose Id right");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Positions = new SelectList(_context.Positions, nameof(Position.Id), nameof(Position.Name));
            return View();
        }
        if (employeeVM.Image!=null)
        {
            string result = employeeVM.Image.CheckValidate("image/", 300);
            if (result.Length > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Positions=new SelectList(_context.Positions,nameof(Position.Id),nameof(Position.Name));
                ModelState.AddModelError("Image", result);
            }
            existed.ImageUrl.DeleteFile(_env.WebRootPath, "assets/img");
            existed.ImageUrl = employeeVM.Image.SaveFile(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "assets", "img"));
            

            return View();
        }
        existed.PositionId=employeeVM.PositionId;
        existed.FullName=employeeVM.FullName;
       
        existed.ImageUrl = employeeVM.Image.SaveFile(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "assets", "img"));
        
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateEmployeeVM employeeVM)
                    
            

    {
        if (!_context.Positions.Any(p => p.Id == employeeVM.PositionId)) ModelState.AddModelError("PositionId", "bele bir position yoxdu");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Positions = new SelectList(_context.Positions, nameof(Position.Id), nameof(Position.Name));
            return View();
        }
        string result = employeeVM.Image.CheckValidate(500,"image/");
        if (result.Length > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Positions = new SelectList(_context.Positions, nameof(Position.Id), nameof(Position.Name));
            ModelState.AddModelError("Image", result);
            return View();
        }
        Employee employee = new Employee
        {
            Name = employeeVM.Name,
            Surname = employeeVM.Surname,
            PositionId = employeeVM.PositionId,
            FacebookUrl = employeeVM.FacebookUrl,
            InstagramUrl = employeeVM.InstagramUrl,
            TwitterUrl = employeeVM.TwitterUrl,
            Salary = employeeVM.Salary,
            ImageUrl = employeeVM.Image.SaveFile(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "assets", "img"))
        };
        await _context.Employees.AddAsync(employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).